# Carrying out a hypothesis test to check whether the marginal effect of education (on wage) is positively related with the level of experience

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, multiple-regression

I used STATA to estimate regression of log of wage (monthly earnings) on education (in years), experience (in years), interaction between education and experience, tenure (years with current employer), age (in years), quadratic age term, married (=1 if married, otherwise 0), black (=1 if African American, 0 if White), south (=1 if living in a Southern state, 0 otherwise), urban (=1 if living in a city, 0 otherwise). This is regression output:

[image]

- I want to see if there is evidence to conclude that the marginal effect of EDUCATION (on wage) is positively related with the level of EXPERIENCE? **I wanted to carry this out using an appropriate hypothesis test.** However, I am unsure what will be my proper hypotheses, test statistic, decision rules, and p-value approach as I have never done a hypothesis test like this one before.
- For my **null hypothesis I took,H0:** there is no linear relationship between the two variables (B=0),
  **alternative hypothesis, H1:** there is a linear relationship between the two variables. Is this correct?
- I am not sure what should be the t-statistic or the p-value in this case. Should I take the p value from the overall model fit bar of the regression output?

Some things I did to check the correlation between the two variables are I got -0.4556 as the correlation value on Stata and I did a scatter-plot to confirm the negative relationship but I am not sure where to start to carry out the hypothesis test in this case.

Comment: hint: look at the interaction term

Comment: can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: okay thank you, i got what i was missing out all this  time